# Flattening List + Future for Scala

Tags: scala, collections, future

I'm trying to await on a funky structure like this: `Future[List[Future[List[Object]]]]`. Await only gets rid of the outer most Future, is there a clean way of trimming this down to a simple `List[Object]`?

Comment: How did you end up with `Future[List[Future[List[Object]]]]`? I am pretty sure you missed a `flatMap` somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`Future.sequence`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]):

```
val original: Future[List[Future[List[Object]]]] = // ...

val futureList = 
  original.flatMap(l => Future.sequence(l)) // Future[List[List[Object]]]
    .map(_.flatten)                         // Future[List[Object]]
```